# Getting Error Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, google-api

I am a newbie in this Android Programming.
This time i want to get data latitude and longitude from MySQL Database.
I have already done sending GPS data from Arduino to my MySQL Database then i want to show it dynamically in my android application using Google Map API.

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final static String TAG = "EasyBle";
    private Handler handler;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private BleManager manager;
    private List<BleDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ScanDeviceAdapter adapter;
    private Handler mhandler = new Handler();
    String nilaiLat;
    String nilaiLong;
    double lat, lng, backupLat, backupLng;
    ProgressDialog loading; //========= EDITED ==============
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();
        initBleManager();
        showDevicesByRv();
        handler = new Handler();
        new Connection().execute();
    }

case R.id.btn_disconnect:
                manager.disconnectAll();
                onPause();
            //========== EDITED ================
            loading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            loading.setTitle("Mendapatkan Lokasi Terkini");
            loading.setMessage("Tunggu Sebentar ..");
            loading.setCancelable(false);
            loading.show();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        loading.dismiss();

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();
            //========== EDITED ================

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            //========== EDITED ================
            intent.putExtra("Latitude", nilaiLat);
            intent.putExtra("Longitude", nilaiLong);
            //========== EDITED ================
            startActivity(intent);


class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";

        String host = "https://gpslocation123.000webhostapp.com/ambil_data_gps.php";
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI (new URI(host));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

            String line = ""; //Data kendaraan akan di simpan disini
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                //break;
            }
            reader.close();
            result = stringBuffer.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return new String("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //Parsing json data disini
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
            int success = jsonResult.getInt("success");
            if(success == 1){
                JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject dtkendaraan = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String longitude = dtkendaraan.getString("longitude");
                    String latitude = dtkendaraan.getString("latitude");

                    nilaiLat = latitude;
                    nilaiLong = longitude;
                }
```

my MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;

    String nilaiLat;
    String nilaiLong;
    double lat, lng, backupLat, backupLng;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //============== EDITED ====================
        String data1 = intent.getStringExtra("latitude");
        String data2 = intent.getStringExtra("longitude");

        lat = Double.parseDouble(data1);
        lng = Double.parseDouble(data2);
        //============== EDITED ====================
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-lat, lng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }


    public void getData(View view)
    {
        new Connection().execute();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LatLng lokasi = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lokasi).title("Posisi Kendaraan"));
                mMap.moveCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                lokasi,
                                16f
                        )
                );
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), lat + ", " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }

    class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = "";

            String host = "https://gpslocation123.000webhostapp.com/ambil_data_gps.php";
            try{
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI (new URI(host));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

                String line = ""; //Data kendaraan akan di simpan disini
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                    //break;
                }
                reader.close();
                result = stringBuffer.toString();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                return new String("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            //Parsing json data disini
            try{
                JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
                int success = jsonResult.getInt("success");
                if(success == 1){
                    JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("data");
                    for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject dtkendaraan = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        String longitude = dtkendaraan.getString("longitude");
                        String latitude = dtkendaraan.getString("latitude");

                        nilaiLat = latitude;
                        nilaiLong = longitude;
                    }
                    if(nilaiLat.equals("") && nilaiLat.equals("")){
                        lat = backupLat;
                        lng = backupLng;
                    }
                    else{
                        lat = Double.parseDouble(nilaiLat);
                        lng = Double.parseDouble(nilaiLong);
                        backupLat = lat;
                        backupLng = lng;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

my Connection.java to connect with my webhost

```
package com.ficat.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String nilaiLat;
    String nilaiLong;
    double lat, lng, backupLat, backupLng;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";

    String host = "https://gpslocation123.000webhostapp.com/ambil_data_gps.php";
    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI (new URI(host));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

        String line = ""; //Data kendaraan akan di simpan disini
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            //break;
        }
        reader.close();
        result = stringBuffer.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return new String("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    //Parsing json data disini
    try{
        JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
        int success = jsonResult.getInt("success");
        if(success == 1){
            JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("data");
            for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject lokasi = data.getJSONObject(i);
                String latitude = lokasi.getString("latitude");
                String longitude = lokasi.getString("longitude");
                nilaiLat = latitude;
                nilaiLong = longitude;
            }
            if(nilaiLat.equals("") && nilaiLat.equals("")){
                lat = backupLat;
                lng = backupLng;
            }
            else{
                lat = Double.parseDouble(nilaiLat);
                lng = Double.parseDouble(nilaiLong);
                backupLat = lat;
                backupLng = lng;
            }

        }
    }
        catch(JSONException e){
//            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

}
this is my php code

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id10329518_yudaihza";
    $password = "   ";
    $dbname = "id10329518_db_gps";
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        echo "Tidak Ada Koneksi";
    } 

    $response = array();
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM location ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $response['success'] = 1;
        $data = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($data, $row);
        }
        $response['data'] = $data;
    }
    else{
        $response['success'] = 0;
        $response['message'] = 'No Data';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

But whenever i open the app, a toast "Value

Comment: HTML (eg. "<br>") is not JSON. Why has the code HTML-or-something-else-that-is-not-JSON? Maybe not asking for correct accept encoding? Maybe calling HTML page? Maybe an error redirect? So many choices! Diagnose backwards. Debuggers are awesome.

Comment: the only file that contain <br> tag is html file that use to fill the database in mysql

Comment: the problem is in your service.. post your php code here. As your service response is giving you warning _Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /storage/ssd2/518/10329518/public_html/ambil_data_gps.php on line 19_. Your json cannot parse that in android

Comment: i have edited my question including my php code, please take a look at it